# Insert SCOPE_IDENTITY at time of insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Insert `SCOPE_IDENTITY` at time of insert?

I have two steps to do this work:

```
INSERT INTO MyDB (Name, Path, File) 
VALUES ('1', 'D:\', '1.Pdf') SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID;

INSERT INTO OtherDB (New, Barcode, FileId)
VALUES ('2', '1', ID);
```

The value `ID` in the second insert comes from the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returned from the first SQL.

Is there any way to do it in a single step?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO OtherDB (New, Barcode, FileId)
VALUES ('2', '1', INSERT INTO MyDB (Name, Path, File) 
                  VALUES ('1', 'D:\', '1.Pdf') SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID);
```

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

This is much, much safer using [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
declare @ids table (id int);

Insert Into MyDB (Name, Path, File)
    output inserted.id into @ids
    Values ('1' ,'D:\', '1.Pdf');

insert into otherdb (New, Barcode, FileId)
    select '2', '1', i.id
    from @ids i;
```

As for your question, this basically requires two inserts because you want to insert into two tables.  You *could* get around this by creating view that combines the two tables and using a trigger on the view.

Comment: Doesn't that need to be `declare @ids table (id int);` ?? I think you're missing the `table` keyword

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @GordonLinoff that an `OUTPUT` clause is useful here. Adding that one can also use `OUTPUT` to insert into 2 different tables in a single `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO MyDB (Name, Path, [File]) 
OUTPUT '2', '1', inserted.ID INTO OtherDB
VALUES ('1', 'D:\', '1.Pdf');
```